# What am I doing wrong? I am trying to add selenium dependencies to Intellij and I keep getting errors

Tags: selenium, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml

POM file:

[image: pom file]

I am trying to add selenium dependencies, but I keep getting errors. I am new to selenium so I am trying to get it setup. Reloading the project didnt help, nor did cleaning up the artifacts. Below is an image of the pom file and the error I am receiving.

```
Cannot resolve org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.1
```

Comment: Instead of adding image, consider providing actual code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try newest version:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Try:

- clean maven project
- reload maven project
- Invalidate Cache & Restart InteliiJ IDEA

Comment: Cleaning and reloading did not work. Same with using the newer version. I am getting this error: Cannot resolve org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.1

Comment: Can you build the project from the command line?

Comment: Is the problem only with this dependency or all dependencies? It is likely Maven cannot access default report maven repositories. Do you use proxies in network? Make sure the command line Maven works. The IDE will also be able to download the dependencies.

Comment: I think the dependencies may be blocked by the firewalls at my work. I was able to successfully install them at home.